# Is squaring both sides of a differential equations valid?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In the equation $ \int \sqrt{y} dy= \sqrt{x} dx $ is it valid to square both sides to obtain $ \int y dy = \int x dx $

Answer (score 2):

In general no, $\int f(y) \,dy = \int g(x) \,dx$ does not imply that $\int f(y)^2 \,dy = \int g(x)^2 \,dx$.

We can see this readily in your example by integrating both equations and observing that we get different solution sets. (I recommend you try carrying this out yourself---I've put the solution sets in a spoiler.)

> The general solution to $\sqrt{y} \,dy = \sqrt{x} \,dx$ is $y = (x^{3 / 2} + C)^{2 / 3}$, but the general solution to $y \,dy = x \,dx$ is $y(x) = \pm \sqrt{x^2 + C}$.

Answer (score -1):

> Assuming it is   $$\int \sqrt{y}dy=\int\sqrt{x}dx$$

Yes you can, but this may increase the number of solutions you get upon solving that equation for some initial term, and a specific value of x.

When you do take the square, keep in mind that square will also work upon $dy$ and $dx$, like in your case:
squaring yields $$ \int y \cdot (dy)^2=\int x\cdot(dx)^2$$

This is useless in your question, squaring both sides will just increase its difficulty, without yielding anything useful.

So, for   $$\int \sqrt{y}  dy=\int \sqrt{x} dx$$
simply integrate both the sides, you get $$ \frac{2}{3} y^{\frac{3}{2}}= \frac{2}{3} 
 x^{\frac{3}{2}}+c$$
$$ y^{\frac{3}{2}}=x^{\frac{3}{2}}+c'$$ as your equation.

Comment: did i post something incorrect?

Comment: Yes, this is complete nonsense...

Comment: What's wrong? please justify...

Comment: Well, when you say that $\left( \int f(x) \, dx \right)^2 = \int f(x)^2 \, (dx)^2$, what does the right-hand side even *mean*?!?

Comment: doesnt mean anything, but cant we  use it in solving diff eqn  when required...and take back root later, isnt it?

Comment: and my solution matches with @Travis $y=(x^{3/2}+c)^{2/3}$

Comment: Yes, the solution that you get when you integrate *directly* obviously agrees with Travis's correct answer. What I'm arguing against is your claim that you can square the integral by squaring the function and squaring $dx$. If you even agree that it doesn't mean anything, why on earth do you think that it's a valid operation to use when solve differential equations?

Comment: yes, thats true...i just wanted to show that it is possible, though useless, so...

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out..:)